# Diplay different kanban view than default

Tags: odoo

i created one custom module, it depends hr and inherit hr.employee.I added new kanban view for hr.employee model, but it showing previous kanban view of hr.employee,both view showing same fields.How to make two different views.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="hr_birthdays.action_window">
      <field name="name">Today Birthdays</field>
      <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
      <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
      <field name="context">{}</field>
      <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree</field>
    </record>

<record id="base.action_partner_form_view1" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="0" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="hr_birthdays.hr_kanban_view_employees_birthday"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="hr_birthdays.action_window"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**1)** Set the priority field to a lower priority (1 goes before 2) than the kanban view you don't want to show up.

**2)** Define a sub action for the tree and kanban view where you define the specific view for your action.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="hr_birthdays.action_window">
    <field name="name">Today Birthdays</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="hr_birthdays.action_window_tree">
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_xml_id_for_the_tree_view"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="hr_birthdays.action_window"/>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="hr_birthdays.action_window_kanban">
    <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_xml_id_for_the_kanban_view"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="hr_birthdays.action_window"/>
</record>
```